# Manually stop / kill scheduled update while attempting to load into memory

Tags: spotfire

Can someone provide a command or way to kill / stop an analysis from loading into memory while it is being opened by the impersonator / scheduled updates user?

I've tried stopping the service, and closing the analysis through the administration console (http://server/SpotfireWeb/Administration/Diagnostics.aspx) but it will not allow it. It will only allow you to close an anlysis that is fully loaded. We are trying to kill an analysis which is taking a long time to load into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Remove it from scheduled updates. Restart website from IIS panel.

Comment: I was hoping for a less intrusive method since restarting the IIS will reset the application pool, clearing the memory, causing me to re-load any and all other scheduled updates into memory.

One work around I found was to just kill the SPID in SSMS.